# How to use apply() with arithmetic functions (R)

Tags: r

In R, how do I use `apply` with arithmetic functions?  For example, given an m-by-n matrix U,  with columns c_1, c_2, ..., c_n, I want to perform the following operation on each column c_i:

for each element u in c_i,

```
u<-u+min(c_i)*sign(min(c_i))*1.05
```

Comment: I think you a good first step would be to write a function that inputs a vector (a column of your matrix) and outputs a vector the way you want. Then you can use `apply(U,2,yourfunction)` to apply it to each vector in the matrix.

Comment: Isn't `min(c_i)*sign(min(c_i))` the same as `abs(min(c_i))`?

Comment: @SamDickson good call.  For efficiency's sake, using `abs` is much better because it avoids an additional call to `min`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
apply(U, 2, function(c_i) { c_i + min(c_i)*sign(min(c_i))*1.05 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that you asked for the answer in regard to `apply`, however, I thought I would include another approach which may be slightly faster.

```
library(matrixStats)
U + abs(colMins(U))[col(U)] * 1.05
```

@Sam Dickson, thanks for pointing out that `abs(min(c_i))` is the same as `min(c_i)*sign(min(c_i))`

Comment: Thanks for this alternative.  Definitely worth looking into.